# laravel gulp watch not updating sass css files

Tags: sass, laravel-5.1, gulp-watch

In our Laravel 5.1 app, we are using elixir and gulp to compile css from sass. When we run just `gulp`, everything compiles correctly and the css files are up to date. Yet, when we run `gulp watch`, and we update a .scss file, Gulp says Sass Compiled successfully, but the css files do not have the newest change. What are we doing wrong?

- added gulpfile.js contents:

  ```
  var gulp = require('gulp');
  var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

  elixir(function(mix){

  mix.copy("vendor/kwizer15/jquery/jquery.js",     "resources/assets/js/jquery.js")
      .copy("vendor/kwizer15/jquery-ui/dist/jquery-ui.js",     "resources/assets/js/jquery-ui.js")
      .copy("vendor/kwizer15/jquery-ui/dist/jquery-ui.css",     "resources/assets/css/jquery-ui.css")
      .copy("vendor/kwizer15/jquery-ui/dist/images/**", "public/images/")
      .copy("vendor/kwizer15/highcharts/highcharts.js",     "resources/assets/js/highcharts.js")
      .copy("vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",     "resources/assets/css/font-awesome.css")
      .copy("vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/fonts/**",     "public/build/fonts/")
      .copy("vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",     "resources/assets/css/bootstrap.css")
      .copy("vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js", "resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js")
      .copy("vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/fonts/**", "public/assets/fonts/")
      .copy("vendor/rjacobsen/jquery-nestable/src/jquery.nestable.css",     "public/css/jquery.nestable.css")
      .copy("vendor/rjacobsen/jquery-nestable/src/jquery.nestable.js",     "public/js/jquery.nestable.js")
      .copy("bower_components/mjolnic-bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/css/**",     "public/css/")
      .copy("bower_components/mjolnic-bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/img/**",     "public/images/")
      .copy("bower_components/mjolnic-bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/**",     "public/js/")
      .scripts(
          [
              'jquery.js',
              'jquery-ui.js',
              'bootstrap.js',
              'highcharts.js'
          ]
      )
      .styles(
          [
              'font-awesome.css',
              'bootstrap.css',
              'jquery-ui.css',
              'custom/nav_styles.css'
          ]
      )
      .phpUnit()
      .version(["css/all.css", "js/all.js"]);

  mix.sass(['reseller_settings.scss'],     'public/css/reseller_settings.css');
  mix.sass(['menu_builder.scss'], 'public/css/menu_builder.css');
  mix.sass(['nav_menu.scss'], 'public/css/nav_menu.css');


  });
  ```

Comment: You'll want to post the contents of your grunt file. I'd suspect you've incorrectly configured your css output for the `watch` task.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I moved the files into the same directory as the main file

Before:
resources/assets/custom

After:
resources/assets/sass/custom